# When I try to pass data to a response in Node I get: "error":{"message":"Cannot read property 'length' of undefined",

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, crud

Whenever I try to pass any data to a response in Node i am getting the above error. Here is my code for my show action:

```
const show = (req, res, next) => {
  User.findOne({"_id": req.currentUser._id}).then(function (user){
    console.log(user.events.id(req.params.id));
    return user.events.id(req.params.id);
   return concert;
  })
    .then(concert => concert ? res.json({ concert }) : next())
    .catch(err => next(err));
};
```

The console.log returns exactly what I would expect. If I change res.json to res.sendStatus('200') I get a 200 back. I think that the error is stemming from when the response tries to calculate the length of the body that it is returning.

Stack Trace Says:

```
Trace
    at /Users/louisarnos/wdi/projects/capstone-project/capstone-backend/app/controllers/events.js:22:12
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at EmbeddedDocument.length (/Users/louisarnos/wdi/projects/capstone-project/capstone-backend/app/models/event.js:48:19)
    at VirtualType.applyGetters (/Users/louisarnos/wdi/projects/capstone-project/capstone-backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/virtualtype.js:77:25)
    at EmbeddedDocument.Document.get (/Users/louisarnos/wdi/projects/capstone-project/capstone-backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:870:18)
    at applyGetters (/Users/louisarnos/wdi/projects/capstone-project/capstone-backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2173:35)
    at EmbeddedDocument.Document.$toObject (/Users/louisarnos/wdi/projects/capstone-project/capstone-backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1957:5)
    at EmbeddedDocument.Document.toJSON (/Users/louisarnos/wdi/projects/capstone-project/capstone-backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2199:15)
    at Object.stringify (native)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Users/louisarnos/wdi/projects/capstone-project/capstone-backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:242:19)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/louisarnos/wdi/projects/capstone-project/capstone-backend/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:151:21)
    at /Users/louisarnos/wdi/projects/capstone-project/capstone-backend/app/controllers/events.js:25:36
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:9)
```

Here is my user schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
  },
  token: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
  },
  events: [EventSchema],
  passwordDigest: String,
}, {
  timestamps: true,
});
```

And my Events schema:

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  artist: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  location: {
    venue: {
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      city: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      region: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      }
    }
  },
  date: {
    month: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    day: {
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      num_of_day: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true,
  toJSON: { virtuals: true },
});

eventSchema.virtual('length').get(function length() {
  return this.text.length;
});

const Event = mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);

module.exports = Event;
```

Comment: I don't think you should be stringifying the object. and `{ concert }` looks weird. unnecessary brackets.

Comment: @KevinB, Yeah you're right. I was messing around trying to fix the error. Same thing happens without it.

Comment: Have you looked through the stack trace to see where the error is occuring? Looked through the source?

Comment: What is here? `/Users/louisarnos/wdi/projects/capstone-project/capstone-backend/app/models/event.js:48:19`

Comment: @KevinB My events model/schema... i'll edit it so the whole file is present instead of just the schema

Comment: Ok, then, the problem is in your virtual length property... `this.text` appears to be undefined.

Comment: @KevinB Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where the error is thrown:

```
eventSchema.virtual('length').get(function length() {
  return this.text.length;
});
```

`text` isn't a property defined in your schema, so it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I had a virtual present at the bottom of my schema, that I wasn't using. It was there as an example on how to build a virtual attribute.